# Custom control SelectedIndexChanged not fired

Tags: vb.net, telerik

**My custom control based on Telerik control**

```
Public Class ComboBoxСountries
    Inherits RadComboBox
End Class
```

**Usage control**

```
<mc:ComboBoxСountries ID="ComboCountry" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoPostBack="true"></mc:ComboBoxСountries>
```

**Event**

```
Protected Sub ComboCountry_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs) Handles ComboCountry.SelectedIndexChanged
    ' not fired
End Sub
```

ComboCountry_SelectedIndexChanged not fired, but if use `<telerik:RadComboBox />` all is ok. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Possibly you need to add custom event handler like this during `OnLoad` event: `ComboCountry.SelectedIndexChanged += New EventHandler(ComboCountry_SelectedIndexChanged)`.

Comment: @Tetsuya Yamamoto thats not how handlers are added in vb.net...

Answer (score 0):

Add OnSelectedIndexChanged="ComboCountry_SelectedIndexChanged" helped

```
<mc:ComboBoxСountries ID="ComboCountry" runat="server" Width="100%" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ComboCountry_SelectedIndexChanged"></mc:ComboBoxСountries>
```